# Effect of adding wet ingredients to dry when making bread?

Tags: baking, bread, dough, mistakes

I inadvertently omitted the eggs from my challah recipe, but realized this only after the final step of mixing in and after fully incorporating the flour.  Rather than throwing everything away, I attempted to resuscitate the dough by adding the eggs.

The dough took on a very odd texture initially, then I kept mixing and added a few tablespoons of extra flour very gradually.  Eventually it resembled the normal dough.

Should my bread turn out alright?  What happens when you add extra liquid to a flour rather than adding the flour last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue you will face is the extra mixing allows for additional gluten development.   In some breads, this could create a risk of over-kneading, which could make the dough less workable, more prone to tearing, and more difficult to get the proper rise.

Challah is a basic egg enriched bread, so other than the eggs themselves (which are fairly effective at helping prevent over-kneading) you don't have a great deal of protection.  The worst case scenario is that your bread will be a little flat and crumbly; the best case is that you are still well within the tolerance window and it will be just fine.

*Edit:  I will leave this for reference, but I was thinking of brioche:*  in a very sweet, fatty bread like brioche, this risk is minimized.  The fat and sugars in the dough act as barriers preventing the glutin-precursors from interacting as frequently or as easily, making it much, much more difficult to over knead.

---

The main reasons for the traditional order of dough assembly are:

- As you no doubt realize, it is much easier to incorporate the liquids evenly into loose flour, rather than a partially formed dough
- The yeast acts on the ingredients present, so sometimes ingredients which inhibit yeast growth are held back until after a fermentation phase
- You want time for all of the flour to be fully hydrated--normally, in yeast raised doughs, this is hardly an issue.